# Animating 'stroke-dashoffset' property with SVG.js

Tags: javascript, svg

I am attempting to create an aniamted dashed line with SVG.js. It is using an SVG generated with Inkscape (saved as plain SVG). 
I can animate some properties correctly (such as rotate). Animating stroke-dashoffset does not work though. I am using the code:

```
var flw1=SVG.get("NetDemandFlow");
flw1.animate({duration:1000}).stroke({dashoffset:100}).loop();
```

I can see in the markup where it has attempted to adjust the property but it does not seem to be doing it correctly (using chrome developer tools):

```
<path id="NetDemandFlow" d="m 261.62928,140.19115 c -0.60098,0 -1.20209,0 -5.7543,0 -4.5522,0 -13.05166,0 -21.55319,0" style="fill:none;stroke:#56baec;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:1.5,1.5;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow1Send)" stroke-dashoffset="20"></path>
```

the part at the end that is:`" stroke-dashoffset="20"`changes rapidly as it animates. This looks incorrect as i would expect it would change the `stroke-dashoffset:0` property earlier in the line. Am i using this module incorrectly or can i just not animate the dashoffset in this way with this module? 
I have also tried using `flw1.attr({'stroke-dashoffset':20});` to change the property and it does the same thing (although not changing).

Comment: You've stroke-dashoffset in style as well as an attribute. I suggest you only want one of these.

Comment: The first one is one Inkscape placed in the SVG, the second one was added by SVG.js. It appears when the stroke function is run.